# Are impeachment hearings having an effect on public opinion?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, impeachment, public-opinion, trump-impeachment

Is there evidence that impeachment hearings are changing public opinion (in either direction). If so, how much is public opinion changing?

Or are both parties (public opinion) pretty much immovable - and had made up their mind beforehand whether or not the impeachment hearings would influence their support for their party.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trump's approval rating has been essentially flat since mid February of 2018, and that hasn't changed. https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/

Impeachment gained maybe 8% during September and October but has also been essentially flat since. https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/impeachment-polls/?ex_cid=rrpromo